# Automating web application with heavy JS with PhantomJS + Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am automating one web application which contains very heavy javascript file. I am using PhantomJS and selenium webdriver with java for automation. 
When the browser launch then on console a lot of errors shown for failure of javascripts used by that application.
And failure of these javascript impacts on the functionality of application.
Anyone faced this problem, give me some appropriate solution.

Comment: i gave up on headless and started spidering/testing with tampermonkey and iframes. i can dance all over a site in one userscript file, using a `switch(` to route. you get full browser features, visual debugging, error resilience (how often does phantom explode compared to chrome), and downright simplicity. just target your userscript to the site in question, then make another page with a list of urls to visit and nav each of those urls with an iframe.

Comment: not got anything..........please expalin clearly :(

Comment: Why don't you share the errors so we can think about solving the problem?

Comment: Actually in this application, Kendo UI is used for designing the front-end UI.All the form elements are designed by using KendoUI

Comment: Errors are: 
[ERROR - 2015-12-18T09:10:26.545Z] Session [212ba0b0-a567-11e5-89de-4d076638150f] - page.onError - stack:
  read (http://{URL}/scripts/scripts.0f71330e.js:14)
  (anonymous function) (http://{URL}/bower_components/kendo/js/kendo.all.min.js:11)
  _queueRequest (http://{URL}/bower_components/kendo/js/kendo.all.min.js:11)
  read (http://{URL}/bower_components/kendo/js/kendo.all.min.js:11)
  query (http://{URL}/bower_components/kendo/js/kendo.all.min.js:11)
  _query (http://{URL}/bower_components/kendo/js/kendo.all.min.js:11)